# Showing users a message while a web page is loading

Tags: php, javascript, android, css, html

I have ported a mobile web app for android. The app is already running very well and it is located here  [CancerBank](http://www.kenyacancerbank.org/www). There are some links that more than 30 seconds to load when a user clicks on them on the android app which can be downloaded here [Android App](http://www.kenyacancerbank.org/Cancer-Ke.apk). Now i want to show the user a message that the page is loading until the page is fully loaded. Does anyone have a plugin that i can use to accomplish this?

My page app is developed in javascript, html5 and css.

Comment: use loader in javascript.....

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this. it seems like a nice plugin.

http://www.gayadesign.com/scripts/queryLoader2/

Comment: this is an image preloader ... The question is about loading a page.

Comment: @Brainfeeder i kind of assumed it worked for the whole page. i guess not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery and the page content is loaded by ajax you can use this:

```
$("body").on({
    ajaxStart: function() { 
        // Your code here
    },
    ajaxStop: function() { 
        // your code here 
    }    
});
```

If you don't use ajax just add a loading `div` when a user clicks on a link. When the page is loaded and the user gets the new content this `div` will be gone again because the page was 'refreshed'.
And if you really want to let them wait to all content of the new page is loaded:
Add a loading `div` which displays always, than use javascript to hide it.

```
window.onload = function() {
    // hide your div
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could hide all your pages elements by default (eg. `<div class='show_this' style='display: none;'>content</div>`) and only show a div containing a "loading" animation. Then you'd show the page elements when the page is loaded. Eg. Put this after you load jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.loading_message').hide();
   $('.show_this').show();
});
```

Something like that might work.